# Can't change author to a custom role in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, roles

I've got a custom role in Wordpress happening with this...

```
add_role('teacher_assistant', 'Teacher Assistant', array(
    'read' => true,
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'delete_posts' => true,
    'edit_others_posts' => true,
    'edit_others_pages' => true,
    'edit_published_posts' =>true,
    'edit_pages' =>true,
    'read_private_posts' => true,
    'moderate_comments' => true,
));
```

...which works fine except for one small problem. When I want to change the author of a post to someone else, anyone with the 'Teacher Assistant' role won't show up in the selection list of authors. It seems only Administrators are available to choose from.

Does anyone know what's going on here and how to resolve it (without a plugin)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i am aware you can only change the author of a post if the new desired author has a role of author or higher.

The solution you have come across will work obviously, but will set the Teacher Assistant Rolea [Contributor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Contributor). Is this what you want? As they will have more authority over s subscriber.

Answer (score -1):

I just found a solution that works:

> $teacher_assistant = get_role('teacher_assistant');
>   $teacher_assistant->add_cap('level_1');